# I need a query that will narrow and organize search results

Tags: mysql, sql

My query gives me all of the info I need, but it is too much and I'm spending too much time manipulating the data in excel.

I need a query that shows me Order Numbers that contain specific SKUs (items) and ALL other SKUs that were in that order.

I have another query that shows the specific SKUs that I need. However, it eleminates the other parts of that order. My query says, for example, show me all orders "where im.Sku like '91323-10-0' or im.Sku like '02105-10-0'"

The SKUs above are pillows. Let's say I order a pillow(91626-10-0) and a tshirt(95523-22-L). Order number is 0999928767463320008.

My current query would not produce the tshirt in the data.

```
select 

p.TrackingNumber
,im.Sku
,convert(text,oh.OrderNumber) as 'OrderNumber'
,convert(date,oh.ShipTime) as 'OrderDate'
,oh.BusinessUnitCode
,oh.OrigShipCode
,oh.ShipCode
,p.ShipWeight
,oh.ShipToRegion

from dmhost.tblOrderHeader oh

join dmhost.tblContainer c on oh.OrderHeaderID = c.OrderHeaderID
join dmhost.tblPackage p on c.ContainerID = p.ContainerID
join dmhost.tblContainerContents cc on c.ContainerID = cc.ContainerID
join dmhost.tblItemMaster im on im.ItemMasterID = cc.ItemMasterID

where (oh.ShipTime between '05/1/2019' and '05/24/2019')
and oh.OrigShipCode like '028'
and  oh.ShipCode like '071'
and (im.Sku like '02105-10-0' or im.Sku like '91323-10-0') --Pillow SKUs

order by oh.OrderNumber
```

This code will give me all pillows that were shipped out between 5/1/19 and 5/23/19.

But, the tshirts, for example,  won't show up.

Comment: You need a subquery in the `where` clause to say  `and oh.OrderNumber in (Select OrderNumber from table where im.sku in ('02105-10-0' , '91323-10-0')`

Comment: 0999928767463320008? I despair.

Comment: `This code will give me all pillows that were shipped out between 5/1/19 and 5/23/19` This statement is patently untrue:`SELECT '5/3/2019' BETWEEN '5/1/2019' and '5/23/2019' x; -> 0`

Answer (score -1):

The comment about a subquery was a close answer.  By looking at your query and the 5 levels deep to get the sku from a given order, you basically need to redo ALL the tables joined twice... Once for the inner qualifying PQ (PreQuery alias) that gets DISTNCT orders based on the sku #s you are looking for.  Once you have that distinct order, THEN go back to the rest of the details and get all components within that order..

To help save a step, I pre-grabbed all the ORDER header fields while I was there.  This way you don't have to go back to the header again just for those values.

```
select 
        p.TrackingNumber,
        im.Sku,
        pq.OrderNumber',
        pq.OrderDate',
        pq.BusinessUnitCode,
        pq.OrigShipCode,
        pq.ShipCode,
        p.ShipWeight,
        pq.ShipToRegion
    from 
        ( select distinct 
                oh.OrderNumber
                convert(text,oh.OrderNumber) as 'OrderNumber',
                convert(date,oh.ShipTime) as 'OrderDate',
                oh.BusinessUnitCode,
                oh.OrigShipCode,
                oh.ShipCode,
                oh.ShipToRegion
            from 
                dmhost.tblOrderHeader oh
                    join dmhost.tblContainer c 
                        on oh.OrderHeaderID = c.OrderHeaderID
                        join dmhost.tblContainerContents cc 
                            on c.ContainerID = cc.ContainerID
                            join dmhost.tblItemMaster im 
                                on cc.ItemMasterID = im.ItemMasterID
            where 
                    oh.ShipTime between '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-24'
                and oh.OrigShipCode like '028'
                and oh.ShipCode like '071'
                    --Pillow SKUs
                and (im.Sku like '02105-10-0' or im.Sku like '91323-10-0') ) pq
            join dmhost.tblContainer c 
                on pq.OrderHeaderID = c.OrderHeaderID
                join dmhost.tblPackage p 
                    on c.ContainerID = p.ContainerID
                join dmhost.tblContainerContents cc 
                    on c.ContainerID = cc.ContainerID
                    join dmhost.tblItemMaster im 
                        on cc.ItemMasterID = im.ItemMasterID
    order by 
        pq.OrderNumber
```

If there was a shorter association from an order to a sku might have shortened this. such as 
OrderHeader -> OrderDetails (item) -> Items (has sku per item), obviously could have made query more compact.

Also, personal preference writing SQL is indentation.  Showing how table A gets to B and B to C, etc gives a visual que to anyone else coming behind you to see the relationships more direct.

Comment: Let's get together between '05/1/2019' and '05/24/2019'; I'll buy you a pint.

Comment: @Strawberry, cute comment and corrected query to yyyy-mm-dd standard.  Readable vs query appropriate not always the same thing :)